# Asymptotics for optimal survival time in a stochastic control problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, oc.optimization-and-control

An individual, henceforth called the *runner* starts at the center of an open ball $\Omega_r \subset \mathbb R^2$ of radius $r > 1$.

At each turn, a vector $x \in S^1$ is chosen uniformly at random,  and the runner may choose to move one unit in the direction $x$ or $-x$ - that is, his new position is just his old position, translated by $x$ or $-x$. The runner’s goal is to stay within $\Omega$ for as long as possible.

Such a choice of moves by the runner is called an *admissible strategy*. Formally, denoting by $X_i$ the uniform choice of angles at each step, an admissible strategy is a sequence of $\{-1, 1\}$-valued random variables that is adapted to the natural filtration of the $X_i$.

Denote by $P_t$ the runner’s position at time $t$, and given fixed $r > 1$ and a strategy $S$, define the exit time $\tau^r_S$ by

$$\tau^r_S := \inf \{t \in \mathbb Z_+ \, | \,P_t \in \Omega_r^c\}.$$

It is true, and not overly difficult to prove that for any $r > 1$, the optimal expected survival time $\sup_{S} \mathbb E[\tau^r_S]$ is finite, where the supremum is taken over all admissible strategies $S$.

**Question:** Is it true that $\log \sup_{S} \mathbb E[\tau^r_S] = \theta(r^2)$ as $r \to \infty$?

*Note: Given functions $f, g > 0$, we say $f(r) = \theta(g(r))$ if there exist $c, C > 0$ and $R > 0$ such that $cg(r) \leq f(r) \leq Cg(r)$ for all $r > R$.*

**Update:** I think I have managed to prove the upper bound, which I will type up upon request. Can we obtain the lower bound?

Comment: I would think that the greedy algorithm, pick the move that gives you the smallest norm, was optimal.  have you tried to analyze it ?

Comment: Yes indeed, I have used that as a starting point for the analysis. Using that I think I managed to get the upper bound - it is a bit complicated but the key idea is to bound it from above by a geometrically distributed random variable. Meanwhile the plan for the lower bound should be to compare it to a biased random walk… I will type up some of the details if it helps.